# UITableView first page of cells are not shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I inherited an old iPhone app that I'm converting from NIBs to a storyboard. One thing that I can't seem to figure out is that the first page of cells in a UITableView is covered by the background color. I've verified that the cells are being created and being filled out. But I just can't see them. Once I scroll down, the lower cells look fine.

TableView code:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return segment_SECTION_HEIGHT;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return segment_CELL_HEIGHT;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSArray * allKeys = [segmentsByTimeDictionary allKeys];
    return allKeys.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *date = [timeSections objectAtIndex: section];
    NSMutableArray *timesegments = [segmentsByTimeDictionary objectForKey: date];

    return timesegments.count;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *date = [timeSections objectAtIndex: section];
    UIView *headerView = [[GradientView alloc] initWithStartColor: segment_SECTION_COLOR_TOP endColor: segment_SECTION_COLOR_BOTTOM];
    headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, segment_SECTION_HEIGHT);
    UILabel *timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
                          CGRectMake(10, 0, 320, segment_SECTION_HEIGHT)];
    timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    timeLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 16];
    timeLabel.text = date;
    timeLabel.textColor = segment_SECTION_TEXT_COLOR;

    [headerView addSubview: timeLabel];

    return headerView;
//    return date;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"segmentCell";
    segmentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
    NSDate *date = [timeSections objectAtIndex: indexPath.section];
    NSMutableArray *timesegments = [segmentsByTimeDictionary objectForKey: date];
    segments *segment = [timesegments objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    [cell setName: segment.name];

    return cell;
}
```

Edited to add: I noticed if I remove this function call from viewDidLoad, then it goes away:

```
drawGradientBackground(self.view, DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_TOP, DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_BOTTOM);
```

That function is defined as

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: (id) startColor.CGColor, (id) endColor.CGColor, nil];
gradient.frame = view.layer.bounds;

[view.layer insertSublayer: gradient atIndex: 0];
```

Screenshot:
[image: UITableView Screenshot]

Comment: After you scroll down and see cells, then scroll back up, what do you see there? Could you please show how you have set up your storyboard?

Comment: After I scroll down and scroll back up, the cells are still covered up. I'm still thinking it has something to do with the gradient.

Comment: Let's try something. Set the `clipsToBounds` of the gradient view to `YES` and see if it helps.

Comment: Why do you want to convert to storyboard?